# Comparing a value to what it was in the previous iteration in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Using Thymeleaf I would like to render the result of a DB query into a structured list, by closing the previous `<ul>` and creating a new sub-list whenever a "menu" or "submenu" value changes in relation to the previous iteration.
For an example, I'd like to convert the follow query results...

```
----------------------------------
| Menu      | SubMenu  | Title   |
|--------------------------------|
| MenuName1 | SubMenu1 | Title1  |
| MenuName1 | SubMenu1 | Title2  |
| MenuName1 | SubMenu2 | Title3  |
| MenuName2 | SubMenu3 | Title4  |
| MenuName3 | SubMenu4 | Title5  |
----------------------------------
```

...into an unordered list like so (for a menu):

```
<ul>
  <li>MenuName1
    <ul>
      <li>SubMenu1
        <ul>
          <li>Title1</li>
          <li>Title2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>SubMenu2
        <ul>
          <li>Title3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>MenuName2
    <ul>
      <li>SubMenu3
        <ul>
          <li>Title4</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>MenuName3
    <ul>
      <li>SubMenu4
        <ul>
          <li>Title5</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have access to both server and client code, so am happy to present a more Thymeleaf friendly format to the template if that's a more elegant solution.

Comment: can you give us an example of the structure of your java objects?

Comment: I don't have anything special really. The DB query just returns a List<Article> where Article has String properties for Menu, SubMenu, Title.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to transform the data into the right format on the server side.

In your example, you'd create classes for `Menu` and `Submenu`:

- Your main class has a `LinkedHashMap<String, Menu>` that maps menu titles to menus
- `Menu` has a `LinkedHashMap<String, Submenu>` that maps submenu titles to submenus
- `Submenu` has a list of `Article`s

Then your Java code iterates over the list of `Article`s, and dynamically creates the `Menu` and `Submenu` instances based on the `menu` and `submenu` properties of the `Article`, and then adds the `Article` to the correct `Submenu`. It's probably helpful to have helper methods `Menu getOrCreateMenu(String title)` in your main class and a `Submenu getOrCreateSubmenu(String title)` in your `Menu` class to handle the logic of creating a new (sub-)menu if one with the given title doesn't exist yet, or returning an existing on if one does (look at `Map.computeIfAbsent` which can do this very concisely).

You then put the whole list of menus in a model and send it to Thymeleaf; the rendering should then be trivial:

```
<ul>
  <li th:each="menu : ${menus}" th:text="${menu.title}>
    <ul>
      <li th:teach="submenu : ${menu.submenus}" th:text=${submenu.title}>
        <ul>
          <li th:each="article : ${submenu.articles}" th:text="${article.title}" />
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```